# Tapping the back button clears search query and results

Tags: bug, android-app, search, tag-search

After searching question by tag and opening a result, tapping the back button is clearing the tag used to query and the results.

Reproduce: `tags` → `[tag]` → tap a question → tap on the back arrow.

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: HUAWEI
- Device Model: PRA-LX1

  - OS Version: 8.0.0 (402(C432))

Comment: The app is no longer maintained.